# Assign Authorship Channel Form

Tags: safecracker

i have a Channel Form that will allow users to apply for a job post, users are registered and logged in when applying, how can i assign the authorship of that entry to the author of the job post (recruiter)? Right now the form works and reflects the author as the job seeker.

Code:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
channel="recruiter_job"  
status="open|featured|draft"
require_entry="yes" 
limit="1" 
dynamic="no"
entry_id="{segment_3}" 
disable="trackbacks|pagination"
}

<h3>Applying for : {title} </h3>
<hr>

{exp:channel:form 
channel="application" 
return="/jobs/apply/ENTRY_ID/application" 
include_jquery="yes"
include_assets="yes" 
error_handling="inline" 
preserve_checkboxes="yes" 
class='custom'
datepicker="no"
logged_out_member_id="{author_id}"
}

 {if global_errors}<ul><li>{global_errors}{error}{/global_errors}</li></ul>{/if}

 {embed="includes/title_job" author_id="{author_id}" } {!-- /EMBED AUTHOR ID OF THE RECRUITER--}

 {field:job_application}
{if error:job_application}{error:job_application}{/if}


{/exp:channel:form} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

So your seeker user is logged in? The `logged_out_member_id` parameter will not work then.

Try setting author_id with a hidden input, e.g.

`<input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="{author_id}" />`

If that also does not work, consider having instead a custom field containing member_id of recruiter.

Comment: Hi Yuri, i've removed the logged_out_member_id parameter and added the <input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="{author_id}" /> with an embed.  {exp:channel:entries status="open|featured|draft" dynamic="no" channel="recruiter_job" limit="1"}
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="{title}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="{author_id}" />
<input type="hidden" name="author" value="{screen_name}" />
{/exp:channel:entries} now i get this error "You are not authorized to perform this action"

Comment: Can you update the post above with how your embed code looks like and how you reference the embed? The excerpt you posted above seems incomplete (and SE comments don't allow nice code formatting...)

Comment: SE comments don't allow nice code formatting, same here..embed code is   {exp:channel:entries status="open|featured|draft" dynamic="no" channel="recruiter_job" limit="1"}
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="{title}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="{author_id}" />
<input type="hidden" name="author" value="{screen_name}" />
{/exp:channel:entries}                                                                                       Pastie: http://pastie.org/10583954

Comment: The code you pasted does not reflect the embed that you reference.

Comment: The "You are not authorized to perform this action" might be because one of the user does not have permissions to post to channel or can't edit entries authored by others.

Comment: Yuri, there was a typo here on EESE my code is http://pastie.org/10584057 i've the member settings all in place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32208/discussion-between-lincolnpixel-and-yuri-salimovskiy).

Comment: Yuri, went back to cross-check the Job seeker group settings "Channel Posting Privileges" and gave the right permissions. It's now working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as accepted then.